# Custom plugin with live templates not working in PHPStorm but does in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've just created a basic plugin which basically adds a live-template / snippet to PHPStorm.

I installed it by zipping the files together, entering PHPStorm > Settings > Plugins and clicking on "Install plugin from disk". After selecting the correct zip file, it appeared in the plugins list, asked me to restart and all worked well - or at least that's what I thought!

My issue is, when I go back to my Settings > Live template the new liveTemplate group doesn't show up and when I try and trigger the live template using "test-tag" followed by TAB it just expands to "" this is not the expected behaviour. Why is this happening??

https://github.com/JasonMortonNZ/test-phpstorm-plugin

**NOTE:** The strange thing is though, when I install the plugin in Intellij IDEA 13 it works perfectly. The live template group appears in the settings and the live templates trigger fine! Why would this be? Sooo frustrating :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Plugin+Compatibility+with+IntelliJ+Platform+Products on how to make your plugin compatible with other IDEs based on IntelliJ Platform.

Comment: I'm not using any platform specific modules, so am I right in thinking that as I'm not including any module dependancy tags it's only compatible with Intellij IDEA? If I add '  <depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>' will this help?

Comment: Hi Yann, I've updated my code and still no joy. Again still working fine in Intellij IDEA but not in PHPStorm? https://github.com/JasonMortonNZ/test-phpstorm-plugin

Comment: Solved: I had to add both:

    <depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>